# Volume by Disc and Shell

Tags: calculus

Find the volume by $A)$Disc/Washer $B)$Shell for $Y^2=6x$, $x=6$, $Y=0$ rotated around $x=0$.

Please check if I set up my integral correctly ? I'm ending up with 
$\frac{1728\pi}{5}$ for both answer, however my friend judged me with his answer $\frac{1728\pi}{10}$. I'm not sure who did wrong here.

A)My integral:

$$\int_{-6}^6 (6)^{2}- (\frac{Y^2}{6})^2 dY$$

B)My integral

$$2\pi\int_0^6 x(2\sqrt{6x}) dx$$

Comment: To get $\pi$, you type \pi.  To get limits on the integral, you put _{lower limit}^{upper limit} after the \int where you can delete the braces if it is just one character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a $\pi$ missing in your setup of the washer (first) integral, but it is obviously a typo, you must have had it correct in your actual work.

The integral should be from $y=0$ to $y=6$, since one of the boundaries is the $y$-axis.

The shell method is done essentially correctly, except for the $2$ inside the integral. You were doubling for the same reason that you integrated from $-6$ to $6$, forgetting about the $x$-axis $y=0$ as a boundary.

Soo in each case there was a misinterpretation of the solid, that is, of the region that is being rotated. Apart from that, things are correct.